# How to refer the environment variable value for s3 bucket name in sam template?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to build  s3 event application by referring the environment variable defined.

Below the template i am referring

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  CreateThumbnail:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler
      Runtime: runtime
      Timeout: 60
      Policies: AWSLambdaExecute
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Sub "${S3}"

      Events:
        CreateThumbnailEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: ""How can refer the s3 bucket form the environment here"
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

i actually need to refer the 'BUCKET NAME' from the 'Environment variable' and also need to add event trigger from the same s3.

can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options,

Either you have defined the S3 bucket in the same template, and then you can reference it using the logical CFN ID:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: my-bucket-name
  CreateThumbnail:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler
      Runtime: runtime
      Timeout: 60
      Policies: AWSLambdaExecute
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Ref S3Bucket
      Events:
        CreateThumbnailEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

Or you do not have it defined in the same template, in which case you have to pass it to the stack as a parameter during deployment like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  S3Bucket:
    Description: Name of the S3 Bucket
    Type: String
Resources:
  CreateThumbnail:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler
      Runtime: runtime
      Timeout: 60
      Policies: AWSLambdaExecute
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Ref S3Bucket
      Events:
        CreateThumbnailEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```